# Getting elements of arraylist based on index in jstl

Tags: java, jstl

This is perhaps a relatively simple thing to do but for some reason I don't seem to get it right.

How does one get an element from an arrayList in jstl based on an index.

In pure java, lets say I have this arralist

```
ArrayList< String > colors = new ArrayList< String >();
   colors.add("red");
   colors.add("orange");
   colors.add("yellow");
   colors.add("green");
   colors.add("blue");
```

if I do `System.out.println(colors.get(1));` I get the first color from the arrayList based
on the index I supplied which happens to be `red`.

Wondering how to achieve that in jstl. I played with the foreach tag in jstl but did not quite get it right.

```
<c:forEach items="colors" var="element">    
 <c:out value="${element.get(1)}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Arralist indexing starts from 0.. so if you say `colors.get(1)` it should return orange

Comment: Is it not just `<c:out value="${element}"/>` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you say `colors.get(1);` or `${element[1]}` its actually referrign to single entry in the list. But when you use `c:forEach` its iterating the loop.
It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you just want the Nth element try

```
<c:out value="${colors[1]}"/> // This prints the second element of the list
```

but rather you want to print the entire elements you should go for loop like

```
<c:forEach items="${colors}" var="element">    
    <c:out value="${element}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Also please note if you write like  `<c:forEach items="colors" var="element">` it literally treat the value as `"colors"`. So if its a variable name you need to give it in `${}` like `${colors}` as depicted in example above.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
 <c:out value="${colors[0]}"/>
```

It will print you "red".

But if you want to print all the values of your list, you can use your `foreach` like that:

```
<c:forEach items="colors" var="element">    
 <c:out value="${element}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This code will iterate over your list `colors` and set each element of this list in a variable called `element`. So, `element` has the same type as the one who parameterized your list (here, `String`). So you can not call `get(1)` on `String` since it does not exist.
So you call directly `<c:out value="${element}"/>` which will call `toString()` method of your current element.

Comment: what will `${element[0]}` print in your code?

Comment: It will call the `toString` method of the element on the first index of the list called `element`, so, it will print "red".

Comment: Have you tried it before posting. It gives `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type java.lang.String`

Comment: Sorry, answer edited: I did not see the `c:foreach` which make no-sense according to the question :).

Comment: @Braj : yes I know, i did not see the foreach. I edit that.

Comment: Now there are two exactly same answers. :)

Comment: @Braj Edited again to explain more :).

Answer (score 0):

You can used array-based access as follows:

```
<c:out value="${colors[0]}" />
```