# passing arraylist<dto> object to javascript as value, then pass it to other jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, arraylist

this is my code, 
i first pass ArrayList object named as list to javascript function.

```
(...)
ArrayList<DTO> list = odc.itemList(); 
(...)

<td><input type = "button" value = "send" onclick="pass('<%=list%>')"></td>
```

second then, i pass the 'list' object to other jsp page like..

```
function pass(p){
  window.location="abc.jsp?info="+p+""; 
}
```

then, i want to recover object in arraylist form... I thought i was able to do like this..

[ Here,abc.jsp]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
String b = request.getParameter("info");
Object obj = b;
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
(...)
```

but i cannot use a method with 'obj' that the original 'list' can 
such as list.add(), list.get(int index).. etc (ArrayList method)

Why can't i? any one knows what problem is with my thinking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019845/getting-elements-of-arraylist-based-on-index-in-jstl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637285/get-specific-element-in-a-list-or-array-using-el